# Convert a number to ...XXg XXs XXc string

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I am using JavaScript in google spreadsheets. I want to convert a number to a "money" representation in the game, which is "X gold X silver X copper". 100 coppers is 1 silver and 100 silvers is 1 gold.

I found this function online:

```
/**
 * Formats the sell value as "Ng Ns Nc" to match the ingame display string.
 */
function formatAsGold(sellValue) {
  var n = sellValue;
  var s = "";
  if (sellValue < 0) {
    s = "-";
    n = Math.abs(n);
  }
  var gold = Math.floor(((n / 10000) % 100));
  var silver = Math.floor(((n / 100) % 100));
  var copper = Math.floor((n % 100)) + "c";
  if (gold == 0) {
    gold = "";
  } else {
    gold += "g ";
  }
  if (silver == 0) {
    silver = "";
  } else {
    silver += "s ";
  }
  return s + gold + silver + copper;
}
```

The problem is, it does not work correctly:

```
a number: 2293900
produces the string: 29g 39s 0c
should be: 229g 39s 0c
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: `Math.floor(((2293900 / 10000) % 100))` returns `29` not `229`.

Comment: `Math.floor(2293900 / 10000)` returns `229`, so it appears you need `var gold = Math.floor(n / 10000);` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `2293900` is the number of coppers, and you want to calculate how many golds, silvers and coppers you need to meet that, this may help...

The `mod` operator returns the *remainder* of the number provided after dividing by the `mod` number, in this case `100`. So that's necessary for the silver and copper but not the gold. First determine the gold pieces, then use the `% 100` to determine the silver, then copper without including the greater valued specie.

```
var gold = Math.floor(n / 10000);
var silver = Math.floor(((n / 100) % 100));
var copper = Math.floor((n % 100)) + "c";
```

There's no higher valued to exclude when determining the gold portion of the "booty" so lose the `% 100` when calculating the gold portion.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BloodyKnuckles/6t5h8jq2/) example.